# "Cannot find module" error when importing mp3

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

I'm using useSound within a NextJS app, and I would like to play a mp3 located in /public/static:

```js
import notification from "../../public/static/notification.mp3"
```

It is working when running `yarn dev` (sound is playing, no errors), but it raises an error when building with `yarn prod`:

```
Type error: Cannot find module '../../public/static/notification.mp3' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Could someone help me with that? I've been looking over the internet/SO/github, and tried several things, including modifying `next.config.js`:

```js
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
      exclude: config.exclude,
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
          options: {
            limit: config.inlineImageLimit,
            fallback: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            publicPath: `${config.assetPrefix}/_next/static/`,
            outputPath: `${isServer ? '../' : ''}static/`,
            name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
            esModule: config.esModule || false,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config;
  },
```

Without success..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok apparently it is as easy as that: update `next-env.d.ts` with

```js
declare module '*.mp3' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

If anyone can explain how that works, it would be nice.

Comment: You forgot to mention you're using TypeScript. TypeScript needs type declarations for different types of files.